# Listing a bucket’s content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();

ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);
foreach (S3Object o in response.S3Objects)
{
        Console.WriteLine(o.BucketName);
}
```

From above code I'm getting Access denied status code(403 forbidden)
I want to show all buckets irrespective of access rights.
How can it be handled ?

Example: In Amazon there are 10 buckets, out of which 2 buckets are not accessible for my credentials. So how to get at-least those 8 buckets which are accessible?

Comment: Are you trying to list the names of the buckets, or list the *contents* of the buckets? Do you wish to do this for the buckets to which you have access, or *all* of the buckets?

Answer (score 1):

Your IAM User/Policy/Role need atleast "list" permissions on s3 along with permissions on individual bucket.

If you do not have "list" permissions; then u need to directly access the bucket.

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply.
Is there a way other than setting those permissions.
Because I'm only provided with **Access Key ID** &  **Secret Access Key**

Comment: I don't want to alter policies which is defined. Instead how can I access buckets which are accessible to my identity

Comment: I don't think that is possible.